# Instruments is not running my iOS application properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I am working in Instruments and need to use the Allocations/Leaks profile, but for some reason my application won't run with those templates. I have a login screen, which is initially presented modally and once logged in will disappear modally as well. It opens the app and begins the login process, but once it logs in it begins to dismiss the page modally, but only makes it down as far as the bottom of the nav bar. It then freezes at that point and I can't do anything, but it continues to profile the running operation. I have reset everything and cleared all data in the iOS simulator. I also tried it on all of the different versions of the simulator including a physical device.

The problem is that this does not occur when I run the app regularly or when I use the Time Profiler template.

Why is Instruments not working with my app when using Allocations/Leaks/Zombies?